# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getLengthLong()J

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jax-rs, wildfly

I am using arquillian to do integration tests against a Restful java API, these tests are executed using `@RunAsClient` annotation, the application is deployed on Wildfly 9.

The application tests were working but suddenly brake.

I am getting this error:

`javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getLengthLong()J`

that seems to be caused by this one:

`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getLengthLong()J`

A piece of code:

```
@RunAsClient
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class AuthTest extends AbstractBlackBoxIntegrationTest {

  private static final String AUTH_URI = API_VERSION + "/auth";

  @Test
  @InSequence
  public void testLoginAsValidUser(@ArquillianResource URL baseURI) {
    WebTarget target = client.target(baseURI.toString()).path(AUTH_URI);
    Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(Entity.entity(getStudentRegularCredentials(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
      assertOk(response);
      response.close();
  }

}
```

This is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                         http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.socialclass</groupId>
<artifactId>api</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>SocialClass API</name>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sargue</groupId>
        <artifactId>mailgun</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-core-api</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-core-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-jpa-module-api</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-jpa-module-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-data-module-api</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-data-module-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-bean-validation-module-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
        <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0.Alpha1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.1.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>sun.jdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jconsole</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.22</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <war.name>api</war.name>
    <deltaspike.version>1.5.1</deltaspike.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.fork>true</maven.compiler.fork>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>${war.name}</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: could you find and share where in your code is the method being used? Or share the entire class/stacktrace for the exception

Answer (score 0):

They've recently updated glassfish code and removed the `ClientRequest.getLengthLong()` and updated HttpUrlConnection code https://github.com/jersey/jersey/commit/4275389f727813aba883a7898f74948b8528018c.

If you update your

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.22</version>
</dependency>
```

to most recent version (or do `<version>[2.22,3.0)</version>`) that should fix all your issues.